# Matching contents from one column to another column in a CSV

Tags: csv

So I have a csv with two columns like this:

```
A B
C D
E F
etc..
```

And another column like this:

```
B
X
D
Y
Z
F
etc..
```

I'd like to match the first column (A,C,E,etc..) to the corresponding values in the last column (B,X,D,Y,etc...).

So that the result is this:

```
A B
  X
C D
  Y
  Z
E F
etc..
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: There are a million ways to solve this.  Did you have any particular programming technology in mind (python/ruby/c++/vb/excel/command shell scripting/whatever)?  ...or are you just asking about what the algorithm would be?

Comment: I really don't even know where to start. I could use excel but the problem is the csv is pretty large, around 1.5 million rows.

Comment: Yes - excel isn't particularly well suited to this (given your file size).  The answer to your question is: write a program to do this.  Pretty much any programming language will do (we can't decide for you, but scripting-type languages are generally easier to learn).  You pick a language, make an effort to write a program that does this, and we help.